# "disk full" error -- quota disagrees with system information

Tags: hard-drive, memory, storage

When I try to download anything or create/save new files, it fails saying "Disk full". Entering `quota` in terminal tells me around 417600 blocks have been used out of 512000. However, going to `About this Mac > More Info > Storage`, it says I've got 938.1 GB free.  Which is most likely wrong, and what do I need to do to be able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would run Verify Disk in the Disk First Aid tab in Disk Utility (Usually kept in Applications > Utilities). If there are any problems you will have to repair your disk which will require restarting while holding down the option key and booting from your recovery partition, or if you have an older computer, from the system install disk.